# How to show with some pixel space imageview

Tags: java, android

So I want to create this as a fragment:

[image: final image]

(trash paint skills)

But Images is not showing up in application, I don't know why.

Sorry for bad English, not native language.

Code:

```
 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "Width:", "" + width);
        Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "How much:", "" + width/30);

        List<ImageView> ballImanges = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        for(int i = 0;i < width/30;i++){

            if((i+1) <= list.size()) {

                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

                imageView.setScaleX(30);
                imageView.setScaleY(30);

                imageView.setLeft(i*30+10);
                imageView.setRight(i*30+10);

                Ball ball = list.get(i);

                imageView.setImageResource(ball.getDrawable());
                ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, i);
                ballImanges.add(imageView);
            }
            else{
                break;
            }

        }

        return ballImanges;
    }
```

Comment: It may be more efficient with drawing on canvas if the number of images are changeable

Comment: @uguboz How should I do that?

Comment: you can start with https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html